# Quartz Cron Expression Issue @ Monthly Jobs Failing

Tags: cron, quartz-scheduler

I have a use case where i want to run a monthly job starting at 2:30 PM for every first friday of every month starting from january.

Cron expression which i use :-

```
0 30 14 ? 1/1 6#1
```

This works absolutely fine.

Sample fire times : -

```
Fri Jan 03 14:30:00 UTC 2020
Fri Feb 07 14:30:00 UTC 2020
Fri Mar 06 14:30:00 UTC 2020
Fri Apr 03 14:30:00 UTC 2020
Fri May 01 14:30:00 UTC 2020
Fri Jun 05 14:30:00 UTC 2020
Fri Jul 03 14:30:00 UTC 2020
```

But if i use the same expression and use December as the starting month

```
0 30 14 ? 12/1 6#1
```

This starts failing :-

```
Fri Dec 04 14:30:00 UTC 2020
Fri Dec 03 14:30:00 UTC 2021
Fri Dec 02 14:30:00 UTC 2022
Fri Dec 01 14:30:00 UTC 2023
```

This kind of becomes yearly.

I don't see any issue with the expression i am using.How do we resolve this or a workaround ?

Answer (score 0):

IMO this mean every 12 month = every December and it is the same as

```
0 30 14 ? 12 6#1
```

and your first record is equal to

```
0 30 14 ? * 6#1
```

(star mean every month)

Comment: the documentation says that for example in this case 0 30 14 ? 12/1 6#1 , 12 here means start in december and /1 means recurrence every month.